# is there a way to call startActivityforResult from either activity or fragment using single instance only

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I am writing a helper class which internally calls `startActivityForResult` , which can be called from either `fragment` or `activity`.

I know indirect work around via loaded method to set `setOnActivityResultReciever(fragment)` , `setOnActivityResultReciever(Activity)`

Is there any way i can avoid overloading ??

overloaded methods

Comment: Please add code snippet

Comment: Please elaborate your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can create common util class and define your start activity If you would like to pass dynamic `intent` value pass the value instead of `intent`.

```
CommonUtils.startActivityForResult(activity, intent); //from activity
CommonUtils.startActivityForResult(fragment, intent); //from fragment
```

Have a look at this code, hope you will get your answer.

```
public class CommonUtils {

    private Activity mActivity;
    private Fragment mFragment;

    public void startActivityForResult(Activity activity, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mActivity = activity;
        startActivityForResult(activity, intent);
    }

    public void startActivityForResult(Fragment fragment, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mFragment = fragment;
        startActivityForResult(fragment, intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what you exactly expecting? Can you elaborate? So, I can help you according.

Comment: i just want to know is it possible without overloading??

Comment: Yes, It's possible startActivityForResult is a method of Fragment class